# How can I pass an array of hidden informations in a POST request in Cake 3.2?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, post, cakephp-3.0

I have created a form for a POST request, but I need to send an array of information that must be not visible in that form.
The array consist in a not specified number of other arrays.

My array is called "$dati" and is made by a not bounded number of arrays with three information each.

The code of my form is:

```
<?= $this->Form->create(null,['type'=> 'post', 'url'=>['action'=>'selectForSell2',$rassegnaselezionata->id,$showselezionato->id,$proiezioneselezionata->id  ]]) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->input('stato', ['options' => ['tutti' => 'Tutti i Soci',  'firmato' => 'Soci Firmati', 'approvato' => 'Soci Approvati'] ] ); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->input('campo', ['options' => ['cognome' => 'Cognome', 'nome' => 'Nome', 'codicefiscale' => 'Codice Fiscale'] ] ); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->input('ricerca', ['label' => false, "class" => " form-control input-medium", "placeholder" => __('Ricerca'), 'visible'=>false]); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Comment: When you say "must not be visible in the form", do you mean that the input elements shouldn't be visible to the normal user looking at the page, or do you mean that even someone who looks at the source of the page should not be able to see the data?

Comment: For my purpose shouldn't be visibile to the normal user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my projects, I have the following element as hidden.ctp:

```
if (isset($model)) {
    $model .= '.';
} else {
    $model = '';
}

foreach ($fields as $field => $values) {
    if (is_array($values)) {
        echo $this->element('hidden', ['model' => $model . $field, 'fields' => $values]);
    } else {
        echo $this->Form->hidden($model . $field, ['value' => $values]);
    }
}
```

Then you can just call it with

```
echo $this->element('hidden', ['fields' => $dati]);
```

Comment: It almost works! 
But I must send an array variable called "dati", which contains n other array (nameless) which contains three data ("socio", "abbonamento" and "biglietto"). 

With your code I send a request with n arrays, but not contained in the "dati" array

Answer (score -1):

If you want to hidden the value of the array  then you can do it in this way.

```html
<?php
                                $a = array("Name" => "Peter", "Age" => "41", "Country" => "USA");
                                ?>

                                <input type="hidden" name="data[Menu][arr]" value="<?php pr($a); ?>">
```

It can produce output like,when you post the data.Check it.it is required or not

```html
Array
(
    [Menu] => Array
        (

            [arr] => Array( [Name] => sradha  [Age] => 20 [Country] => IN)


        )

)
```